# In which Death Note manga chapter does L die?

Tags: death-note

I want to start reading Death Note manga but I have already seen the anime till L's death. Which manga chapter should I start reading from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L dies in [chapter 58 named "Feelings Within"](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Feelings_Within).